# Remove duplicate data from database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new in php. I have to fetch a large amount of data from database where all of duplicate data will be removed. here is my database:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVz2Q.png

My output will be :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1QTC.png

Here start time will be 10 am to 3 pm and rest are end time. when start/end time two data found fast data will be counted

Comment: If you want to manage a large amount of data i recommend you to do inside SQL service doing a TRIGGER or a PROCEDURE, but doing inside SQL not on PHP because you must use a lot of memory and you could lockdown the server.

Comment: How can I use sql triggers

Comment: What database server do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I supose that you know to do a mysql query...**

In your PHP do:

```
$mysqlresult = query (....,'
        select distinct ac_no 
        from ?¿?¿?
        order by sTime desc
    ');

foreach ($mysqlresult as $key=>$var){
    query(...'
    DELETE FROM ?¿?¿? t
       WHERE t.ac_no = '.$var['ac_no'] .'
         and t.sTime != '.$var['sTime']);
```

Now you have deleted from your database everything.

ANALYST CODE, PLEASE DO CORRECTLY ON PHP (and please, log and comment something)